# How to fade the content of cell of table view which reaches at the top while scrolling?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Hi everyone i need to implement this functionality.I need to fade the content of the cell while its going to disappear, i mean while it reaches at the top of table view.I am not getting how to do that.Please help me.I tried to use the scrollview's method but not getting how to do that.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fading a UIView on top of a UITableView with Sections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160052/fading-a-uiview-on-top-of-a-uitableview-with-sections)

Comment: @WrightsCs that not the duplicate ,firstly read my question properly ,i don't need to fade the view only.I know how to do that,but i want to fade cell content when its going to invisible,if you know then help.Cheers

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**For anyone who wants it, here's some ready-to-go copy/paste-able code that is fully working:**

*Best Part: This code is only reliant on ONE outside property:* `self.tableView`*, so just make sure that's set up and you're good to go!*

Just stick this method in your view controller somewhere:

```
#pragma mark - Scroll View Delegate Methods

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    // Fades out top and bottom cells in table view as they leave the screen
    NSArray *visibleCells = [self.tableView visibleCells];

    if (visibleCells != nil  &&  [visibleCells count] != 0) {       // Don't do anything for empty table view

        /* Get top and bottom cells */
        UITableViewCell *topCell = [visibleCells objectAtIndex:0];
        UITableViewCell *bottomCell = [visibleCells lastObject];

        /* Make sure other cells stay opaque */
        // Avoids issues with skipped method calls during rapid scrolling
        for (UITableViewCell *cell in visibleCells) {
            cell.contentView.alpha = 1.0;
        }

        /* Set necessary constants */
        NSInteger cellHeight = topCell.frame.size.height - 1;   // -1 To allow for typical separator line height
        NSInteger tableViewTopPosition = self.tableView.frame.origin.y;
        NSInteger tableViewBottomPosition = self.tableView.frame.origin.y + self.tableView.frame.size.height;

        /* Get content offset to set opacity */
        CGRect topCellPositionInTableView = [self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForCell:topCell]];
        CGRect bottomCellPositionInTableView = [self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForCell:bottomCell]];
        CGFloat topCellPosition = [self.tableView convertRect:topCellPositionInTableView toView:[self.tableView superview]].origin.y;
        CGFloat bottomCellPosition = ([self.tableView convertRect:bottomCellPositionInTableView toView:[self.tableView superview]].origin.y + cellHeight);

        /* Set opacity based on amount of cell that is outside of view */
        CGFloat modifier = 2.5;     /* Increases the speed of fading (1.0 for fully transparent when the cell is entirely off the screen,
                                     2.0 for fully transparent when the cell is half off the screen, etc) */
        CGFloat topCellOpacity = (1.0f - ((tableViewTopPosition - topCellPosition) / cellHeight) * modifier);
        CGFloat bottomCellOpacity = (1.0f - ((bottomCellPosition - tableViewBottomPosition) / cellHeight) * modifier);

        /* Set cell opacity */
        if (topCell) {
            topCell.contentView.alpha = topCellOpacity;
        }
        if (bottomCell) {
            bottomCell.contentView.alpha = bottomCellOpacity;
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add `<UIScrollViewDelegate>` to your class's '.h' file!

You may also want to put a call to this method somewhere in your `viewDidLoad` method like this: `[self scrollViewDidScroll:self.tableView];` so that the bottom cell will start out faded (since it's normally cut off by the table view edge).

TIP: Set your table view separator style to none (`self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;`), or create your own separators as images and add them as a subview to your cells, so that you don't get the unpleasant effect of the separators disappearing without fading.

*Works just as well with smaller than full-screen table views.*

Comment: That works exactly.....+1....But I had found the answer before...thanks for your comment though as it can help others as well.....

Comment: Works great! Ill be saving this little snippet.

Comment: Is there anyway to fade out the table cell separator line too?

Comment: Yeah. Add the separator line as a subview to your cell's contentView. This code works by fading out everything that is a subview of the contentView, so anything that is not a subview of that (ie. the default tableView separators) won't be faded. An easy way to work around this is to remove the default separators (self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;), and then create an image in a program like GIMP or Photoshop, the exact width and height of the separator line you'd like to see, and add that image as a subview of your cell's contentView using a UIImageView.

Answer (score 6):

Here is Fateh Khalsa's solution in Swift

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)
{
    let visibleCells = tableView.visibleCells

    if visibleCells.count == 0 {
        return
    }

    guard let bottomCell = visibleCells.last else {
        return
    }

    guard let topCell = visibleCells.first else {
        return
    }

    for cell in visibleCells {
        cell.contentView.alpha = 1.0
    }

    let cellHeight = topCell.frame.size.height - 1
    let tableViewTopPosition = tableView.frame.origin.y
    let tableViewBottomPosition = tableView.frame.origin.y + tableView.frame.size.height

    let topCellPositionInTableView = tableView.rectForRowAtIndexPath(tableView.indexPathForCell(topCell)!)
    let bottomCellPositionInTableView = tableView.rectForRowAtIndexPath(tableView.indexPathForCell(bottomCell)!)
    let topCellPosition = tableView.convertRect(topCellPositionInTableView, toView: tableView.superview).origin.y
    let bottomCellPosition = tableView.convertRect(bottomCellPositionInTableView, toView: tableView.superview).origin.y + cellHeight

    let modifier: CGFloat = 2.5
    let topCellOpacity = 1.0 - ((tableViewTopPosition - topCellPosition) / cellHeight) * modifier
    let bottomCellOpacity = 1.0 - ((bottomCellPosition - tableViewBottomPosition) / cellHeight) * modifier

    topCell.contentView.alpha = topCellOpacity
    bottomCell.contentView.alpha = bottomCellOpacity
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I hope i understand your question correctly: You need to fade the content of the cell depending on how much that cell is out of the screen?

I don't know what cells you have in the table, but IF they have the same height, you can do something like this:

```
// Let's say you have a variable called cellHeight
int cellHeight = 80;

// Get the location of the top of the table
int topPosition = (int)tableView.cotentOffset.y;

// Get the index of the cell
int cellIndex = topPosition  / cellHeight;  

// Determine how much the cell is outside the view
float opacity = 1.0f - ((topPosition  % cellHeight) / cellHeight);
```

You can now use `opacity` to control the transparency level. 0.0f means completely outside the view, 1.0f means completely inside.

To get the actual UITableViewCell which you need to change, use

```
- (NSArray *)indexPathsForVisibleRows
```

and then search for the cell that `cellIndex`.

Comment: @Andrei you are almost right,but in which method i need to use that,could you help me more...

Comment: i used in this way  
 int cellHeight = 50;
 
 // Get the location of the top of the table
 int topPosition = (int)translationTableView.contentOffset.y;
 
 // Get the index of the cell
 int cellIndex = topPosition  / cellHeight;  
 
 // Determine how much the cell is outside the view
 float opacity = 1.0f - ((topPosition  % cellHeight) / cellHeight);
 
 NSArray *indexes = [translationTableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
 
 for (indexpath in indexes ) 
 {
  
  if (cellIndex) 
  {
   cell.contentView.alpha=1.0;
   
  }
  
 }  but its fading many rows,please help me out how to do that.....

Comment: I guess you can put it in `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`

Comment: @Andrei i did it in the same method,but it fades many cells not the desired cell.Help me to do so,see the image.

Comment: @Andrei see the logic as i did given told by you is this correct or need to do some changes...

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Can you post the code you wrote in scrollViewDidScroll?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a gradient image and place it above the top of your scrollview.  If you would like the "fade" to only be visible during scrolling, you can animate the image fading in and out on scrollViewBegin/DidEndScrollingAnimation or combine that with scrollViewDidScroll, you can decide when it's appropriate to fade out (i.e. when you're scrolled to the top).

Comment: that's not my question, i need to fade the content of the cell which is going to disappear at the top of table view.I will put an image here just see that.....

Comment: I need to find out which cell reaches at the top how to know that..so that i can fade it..